# Laravel File Upload with Ajax Show 405 Method Not Allowed Error on Large File Size 20 MB

Tags: ajax, laravel, file, upload

I am uploading a file using Laravel 5.7 and ajax.

When i upload file up to 5 MB it is working fine. when i am trying to upload 37MB file. it show 405 method not allowed error.

but it is uploading 50 MB file on my local system very fast, but code not working on live server.

I Already make settings in php.ini

*max_execution_time = 600, max_input_time = 600, memory_limit = 4096M, post_max_size = 100M, upload_max_filesize = 100M*

Comment: Did you restart your server and maybe use `phpinfo()` on a page to check if your values are in effect?

Comment: @kerbh0lz yes i checked phpinfo() on server. All settings are effected there.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this that worked for me, it was not php.ini or **Laravel** problem, it was a configuration of my **nginx** server script.

If you using Nginx, I found that the solution is to add `client_max_body_size 20m;` you can set max body size in your server configuration.

- 20m is 20 MB which the max files size I did want to upload.

Source: [Serhii75@Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cors-error-when-uploading-file?page=1&replyId=710808)